# objective encode in utf8 instead of unicode

Tags: objective-c, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, urlencode

I'm having a problem with objective C and Hebrew characters.
I'm trying to get information from a `NSURL` to an `NSMutableDictionary`.

I'm using `objectForKey:[url absoluteString]`
The problem is for example for the string

```
A%20%d7%91%d7%93%d7%99%d7%a7%d7%94%20%d7%a2%d7%9d%20%d7%90%d7%95%d7%aa%20%d7%95%d7%a8%d7%95%d7%95%d7%97
```

which is decodes to

```
A ××××§× ×¢× ×××ª ××¨×××
```

instead of

```
A בדיקה עם אות ורווח
```

How can I take the first text with the "x"s and convert it to the the second text with the Hebrew?

I used this site and saw that it can be possible
[first Site](https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter)

Thank You!

Comment: Show your relevant code, as text, in your question.

Comment: There is no such thing as "utf-8 instead of unicode". utf-8 _is_ a unicode encoding, and unicode itself is not an encoding but a system of representing symbols as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear why you think this decodes to a string with "×" in it (which is not the same as "x"). This decodes into Hebrew without trouble:

```
let text = "A%20%d7%91%d7%93%d7%99%d7%a7%d7%94%20%d7%a2%d7%9d%20%d7%90%d7%95%d7%aa%20%d7%95%d7%a8%d7%95%d7%95%d7%97"

(text as NSString).removingPercentEncoding
```

The equivalent ObjC should be close to this:

```
NSString *text = @"A%20%d7%91%d7%93%d7%99%d7%a7%d7%94%20%d7%a2%d7%9d%20%d7%90%d7%95%d7%aa%20%d7%95%d7%a8%d7%95%d7%95%d7%97"
NSString *decoded = [text removingPercentEncoding];
```